# DatePicker textvalue is updating to one day prior instead of date selected

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement a date picker view on my app however, when I select a date on the calendar view it updates the text to one day prior instead of the selected date. I'm assuming it has to do with the formatting function. I'm using Android Jetpack Compose and followed a tutorial from Medium that explains the implementation but its not working as expected. Thank you in advance.

```kotlin
@ExperimentalComposeApi
@Composable
fun DatePickerview() {

    var datePicked: String? by remember {
        mutableStateOf(null)
    }

    val updatedDate = { date: Long? ->
        datePicked = DateFormater(date)
    }

    val activity = LocalContext.current as AppCompatActivity

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopStart)
            .padding(16.dp)
            .border(3.dp, DarkerButtonBlue, RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
            .clickable {
                showDatePicker(activity, updatedDate)
            }
    ) {
        ConstraintLayout(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {

            val (label, iconView) = createRefs()

            Text(
                text = datePicked ?: "Event Date",
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .constrainAs(label) {
                        top.linkTo(parent.top)
                        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                        end.linkTo(iconView.start)
                        width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                    }
            )

            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.DateRange,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(30.dp)
                    .constrainAs(iconView) {
                        end.linkTo(parent.end)
                        top.linkTo(parent.top)
                        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    },
                tint = Color.DarkGray
            )

        }

    }
}

fun DateFormater(milliseconds: Long?): String? {
    milliseconds?.let {
        val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US)
        val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(it)
        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime())
    }
    return null
}


fun showDatePicker(
    activity: AppCompatActivity,
    updateDate: (Long?) -> Unit
) {
    val picker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().build()
    picker.show(activity.supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())
    picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
        updateDate(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you able to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your problem is with your time zone, try specifying it:

```kotlin
fun DateFormater(milliseconds: Long?): String? {
    milliseconds?.let {
        val formatter = java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US)
        val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        formatter.timeZone = calendar.timeZone
        calendar.timeInMillis = it
        return formatter.format(calendar.time)
    }
    return null
}
```

Also a little off-topic. Using `ConstraintLayout` for such a simple layout is unnecessary. You can use `Row` with the `weight` modifier for your text: in this case the size of `Icon` will be calculated before the size of `Text`, see [`weight` modifier documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#weight) for details.

```kotlin
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(16.dp)
) {
    Text(
        text = datePicked ?: "Event Date",
        color = Color.White,
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
    )

    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.DateRange,
        contentDescription = null,
        tint = Color.DarkGray,
    )
}
```

Comment: thank you Philip, where would I put this in the DateFormater function?

Comment: @mxgenius I've updated my answer with full code of your `DateFormater`

Comment: Philip, thank you for the continued support. that calendar is still not updating with selected date. Any other ideas? So frustrating...

Comment: @mxgenius Add logs, check out what's `Date(milliseconds)` will output, and compare `milliseconds` to some online timestamp converter

Comment: Thank you for your help Philip. I will have to keep looking for something that works but I appreciate your help.

Comment: @mxgenius so this didn't help? I'm afraid that without [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's really hard to solve your problem, as even your original code works fine to me. An in case of 1 day difference, time zone is the first thing that comes to mind. Have you tried logs as I suggested? What's output?

Comment: Philip, you are so kind. Thank you for continuing to help me. I was afraid that I was taking too much of your time. I did use the log cat. I set the date in the datePickerDialog for 9/28. However the Log.v output showed displayed the following: "2021-09-28 11:32:30.702 22551-22551/com.example.fieldservice V/DatePicker: Mon Sep 27 17:00:00 PDT 2021" As you can see its one day before. Any other ideas?

Comment: @mxgenius No problem, I'm here to help you =) Are you using `com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0`? It doesn't seems like a compose issue, if you're using latest version (`1.4.0`), try reporting this problem to [material-components-android github](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)

Comment: Yes I have it at 1.4.0. I will report it as you mentioned. Thank you for your patience and help.